# How to extract data from Highcharts while the Charts array is empty?

Tags: javascript, selenium, charts, highcharts

I am trying to extract data from a [chart](https://www.tgju.org/profile/gold_mini_size) in Highcharts library. I have tried the following code on Highcharts's demo and it works well. In my case, the `chart` array is empty, though the data has been populated. How to extract the data in this case?

My target chart: `//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div`

```
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].options.data
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].processedYData;
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].processedXData;
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data 
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].points
```

Comment: Hi @Edin, There is no easy way to get chart data from the website. An author of the page probably intentionally blocked this possibility and don't want to allow to scrape data.